# Error occurs with anonymous block pl/sql for multiple Update statement

Tags: sql, plsql, sql-update

I am having problems in following pl/sql anonymous. Here is the scaled down version of my pl/sql block..What is wrong with my code?

`WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT sql.sqlcode ROLLBACK`

```
WHENEVER oserror EXIT FAILURE ROLLBACK
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SET ECHO OFF
SET DEFINE OFF
SET LINESIZE 120
SET AUTOCOMMIT OFF
BEGIN
update MYTABLE set GID = '12345' where MYTABLE.COLUMN1=456456 and MYTABLE.PARTY<>0 and MYTABLE.EXPIRY = to_date('17/05/2013','DD/MM/YYYY')
AND EXISTS (SELECT PARTIES.LABEL
        FROM PARTIES 
        WHERE PARTIES.m_id = MYTABLE.PARTY_ID and PARTIES.LABEL = 'PARTY_NAME');    
dbms_output.put_line( 'Rows Updated : ' || to_char(sql%rowcount));
END;
/
```

Here is the output I get

```
update MYTABLE set GID = '12345' where MYTABLE.COLUMN1=456456 and MYTABLE.PARTY0 and MYTABLE.EXPIRY = to_date('17/05/2013','DD/MM/YYYY')
       *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 8:
PL/SQL: ORA-06552: PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated
ORA-06553: PLS-488: invalid variable declaration:  object 'TIMESTAMP' must be a type or subtype
ORA-06550: line 2, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error you have reported I am guessing that somewhere in your PL/SQL block (which is not present in your question) you are referring to a table column named `TIMESTAMP`. Unfortunately this as a reserved word in Oracle as it is a column data type. I would recommend that you rename the column to something like `DATE_CREATED` and see if your code compiles.